# How to resolve variables in Perl

Tags: perl

I need help resolving the following variable `${$mapusers[$index]->[1]}`

See below... It prints find. But when I do a system($query_user) the variable is empty.

```
my $query_user = 'adquery user -w ${$mapusers[$index]->[1]}';
```

Comment: Try to do this my $query_user = "adquery user -w ".${$mapusers[$index]->[1]};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the `adquery` command and store its output in `$query_user`, use [backticks or `qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60):

```
my $query_user = `adquery user -w ${$mapusers[$index]->[1]}`;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `"` instead of `'`:

```
my $query_user = "adquery user -w ${$mapusers[$index]->[1]}";
system($query_user);
```

Or, if that one doesn't work, try this:

```
my $query_user = "adquery user -w " . $mapusers[$index]->[1];
system($query_user);
```

The first one should be used if `$mapusers[$index]->[1]` is a scalar reference, and the second one should be used if `$mapusers[$index]->[1]` isn't a reference.

If you want to capture the stdout of the command, use `readpipe` instead of `system`, or use the backtick operator.